# Efficiently collect data from 2 large DataFrames and merge it in to a numpy array

Tags: python, performance, pandas, numpy, merge

I have 2 large dataframe's which are too big for merge.
Both contain user log data for different months.
I need to **efficiently** collect all data for each id, and create an img/array.

### Example

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler,MinMaxScaler
import time

n_rows = 90000000
cols = [ 'id','date','d1','d2','d3']

df_march = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,100, size=(n_rows, len(cols))), 
                        index=np.arange(n_rows), columns=cols)
df_feb = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,100, size=(n_rows, len(cols))), 
                        index=np.arange(n_rows), columns=cols)
```

### What I tried

```
def create_img_for_id(id):

    start = time.time()  
    df = df_march[df_march.id==id]
    end = time.time()
    print 'collecting march data:', end - start
    start = time.time()  
    df = df.append(df_feb[df_feb.id==id])
    end = time.time()
    print 'appending feb data: ', end - start
    start = time.time() 
    df = df.sort_values(by=['date'], ascending=[False])
    end = time.time()
    print 'sort', end - start

    start = time.time() 
    img = StandardScaler().fit_transform(df[['d1','d2','d3']])
    end = time.time()
    print 'fit', end - start
    return img

img = create_img_for_id(8)
```

### The result

```
collecting march data: 31.3800001144
appending feb data: 10.9200000763
sort 0.576999902725
fit 0.484999895096
```

I need to create the img data in batches for learning process. around 526 images each. I need to create it dynamically, due to memory limitation.  How can I use groupby for my problem ? or any other efficient way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will do it with `groupby` `get_group`

```
gmacth=df_march.groupby('id')
gfeb=df_feb.groupby('id')
gmacth=df_march.groupby('id')
df=pd.concat([gfeb.get_group(8),gmacth.get_group(8)]).sort_values(by=['date'], ascending=[False])
img = StandardScaler().fit_transform(df[['d1','d2','d3']])
```

Comment: I get an error: at line : pd.concat([gfeb,gmacth]).sort_values(by=['date'], ascending=[False]).The error is: TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type "<class 'pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy'>"; only pd.Series, pd.DataFrame, and pd.Panel (deprecated) objs are valid

Comment: I think it should be: df=pd.concat....  now its working, and its more efficient. Thank you :)